# React Native SHA256 hasher with crypto-js

Tags: react-native, cryptography, cryptojs, pbkdf2

I am trying to use the `crypto-js` `pbkdf2` algorithm in React Native. I swear I had it working, walked away from my computer and everything broke...

I am trying to create a password hash by `await pbkdf2Sync(password, nonceData.salt, {hasher:cryptojs.algo.SHA256, iterations: 500, keySize: 32}).toString().substring(0,64);` however `cryptojs.algo.SHA256` is undefined.

I import everything like so

```
import pbkdf2Sync from 'crypto-js/pbkdf2'
import cryptojs from 'crypto-js/core'
```

but if I print cryptojs.algo to console I get that it only has SHA1, HMAC and PBKDF2.

How can I get the SHA256 algorithm to work?

I am using cryptojs 3.3.0 `"crypto-js": "^3.3.0",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2023, most of modern browser supports Crypto API. If your target user using modern browser such as chrome and edge, just use [Crypto API](https://caniuse.com/cryptography):

```js
const text = 'hello';

async function digestMessage(message) {
  const msgUint8 = new TextEncoder().encode(message);                           // encode as (utf-8) Uint8Array
  const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', msgUint8);           // hash the message
  const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer));                     // convert buffer to byte array
  const hashHex = hashArray.map((b) => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join(''); // convert bytes to hex string
  return hashHex;
}

const result = await digestMessage(text);
console.log(result)
```

Then you could verify the result via [online sha256 tool](https://fe-tool.com/en-us/hash/sha256/?inputText=hello).